# Are Java constants availble for usage from within Play! templates?

Tags: java, templates, playframework

I have a User entity:

```
@Entity
public class User extends PortalModel {

    ...

    public enum Role {
        User,
        Admin,
    }

    @Required
    public Role role;

    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return role == Role.Admin;
    }
}
```

And I tried to use this template:

```
#{if user && user.role == User.Role.Admin}
    <li>
        <a href="/admin">Admin</a>
    </li>
#{/if}
```

This failed, and I suspect the reason is that you can only access the model objects themselves from template, but not other runtime classes, including even enum constants. I moved to defining and using the isAdmin() method:

```
#{if user && user.isAdmin()}
```

And this worked. I think I'm right, but would just like a confirmation - is it true that the only java objects you can access from the template are the model classes themselves, that are passed along in `render()` or put in `renderArgs` ?

Comment: The docs say the template expression syntax is Groovy, so this should be possible. Try using the fully qualified name for `User`?

Comment: @Inerdia - it works! Post this as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [template engine docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/templates) for Play! say the expression syntax is Groovy, so this should be possible. Try using the fully qualified name for `User`.